# "Die unglaubliche Frage des Raffael V."

Tags: grammar, style

Ich lese viel (zu oft) spiegel.de und mir ist irgendwann aufgefallen, dass man dort dazu neigt eine bestimmte (gekünstelte) Formulierung für Betitelungen zu nutzen, welche wohl dazu bestimmt ist eine Aura der Bedeutungsvölligkeit, Tragik und Mysterium aufzubauen - ein paar Beispiele:

1. "[Quelle-Erbin als Zeugin vor Gericht: **Der Jammer der Madeleine Schickedanz**](http://www.spiegel.de/wirtschaft/unternehmen/quelle-erbin-schickedanz-im-oppenheim-prozess-als-zeugin-a-958542.html)"
2. "[Mumienfund in den USA: **Der einsame Tod der Pia Farrenkopf**](http://www.spiegel.de/panorama/gesellschaft/mumie-in-michigan-frau-lag-fuenf-jahre-tot-in-garage-a-961488.html)"
3. "[In der DEA-Falle: **Der unglaubliche Fall des Dennis G.**](http://www.spiegel.de/video/in-der-dea-falle-der-unglaubliche-fall-des-dennis-g-video-1336338.html)"
4. "[Ermittlungsfehler in Berlin: **Der vermeidbare Tod des Tahir Özbek**](http://www.spiegel.de/panorama/justiz/rockermord-an-tahir-oezbek-innensenator-henkel-raeumt-lka-fehler-ein-a-964701.html)"

Um mich fundierter über diese grässliche Stilblüte echauffieren zu können bräuchte ich für das Kind einen Namen. Gibt es hierfür eine grammatikalische oder informelle Bezeichnung?

Comment: Ist das wirklich grässlich? Wenn man einen Deutschkurs besucht, wird dieser Stil einem eigentlich beigebracht, um Vielfältigkeit beim Schreiben zu fördern. (Vieleicht nicht genau diesen Stil, aber den Nominalstil bei Betitelungen schon.)

Comment: Bin ich der einzige, den das an Milan Kundera ("Die unerträgliche Leichtigkeit des Seins") erinnert?

Comment: @c.p. Diese Beurteilung ist zugegebenermaßen sehr subjektiv natürlich. Der Grund weshalb ich diesen Stil nicht mag ist einmal, weil ich bei einer Nachrichtenquelle eher einen klaren und schnörkellosen Stil erwarte - und das ist hier nicht gegeben, was auch gleichzeitig ein zweiter Grund ist. Ich persönlich finde dieser Stil versucht mir eine emotionale und tragische Perspektive aufzuzwingen - Manipulativität ist immer unsympathisch. Außerdem klingt dieser Stil irgendwie literarisch Gernegroß - auch unsympathisch.

Comment: @Ingmar: Das könnte eventuell auch in die Kategorie "Nominalstil" fallen. Allerdings handelt es sich bei dem Buch um einen fiktionalen Roman und der Personenname fehlt - dieser muss möglichst mit abgekürztem Nachnamen vertreten sein!

Comment: Guter Punkt. Dann also Böll: "Die verlorene Ehre der Katharina Blum". Da wäre dann ja auch der Bezug zur "ZEITUNG" wieder gegeben.

Comment: Genau ... und wenn ich so einen Artikeltitel bei spiegel sehe, dann höre ich den Autor rufen: "Ich, ich, ich will auch ein Böll sein!"

Comment: @c.p. Also im Deutsch-Unterricht in der Schule wurde mir früher beigebracht solche Formulierungen als unseriös zu erkennen und selbst zu vermeiden (mit "Bild"-Beispielen). Das sind so typische dramatische Boulevard-Formulierungen, die leider in vielen Online-"Nachrichten"-Magazinen genutzt werden. Man merkt auch, dass gerade die wenigen seriösen Quellen auf solche Formulierungen i.d.R. verzichten (z.B. Tagesschau). Mein persönlicher Favorit einer Online-Magazin-Nachricht ist immernoch der "Horrorflug der Spielerfrauen". Dramatik pur :D http://bit.ly/1h6vppr

Comment: Alles klar, danke, ich sehe jetzt euren Punkt (@DominicDeCoco und Raffael).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dieser, vor allem bei sog. Klatschblättern verbreitete Betitelungsstil wird [Nominalstil](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalstil) genannt. In diesem Fall wird, wohl um eine Assoziation zum berühmt-berüchtigten Vorreiter aller Klatschblätter  des Axel-Springer-Verlages zu vermeiden. Gebrauch von genitivischen Konstruktionen gemacht.

Wie im verlinkten Wikipedia-Artikel erwähnt, finded dieser Stil auch in Dissertationen, Forschungspapieren und behördlichen Texten häufig Verwendung

Answer (score 2):

Der Sinn vonTiteln und Schlagzeilen ist es, Aufmerksamkeit zu erregen, außerdem müssen sie kurz und prägnant sein.
Jounalistischer Stil hat seine  negativen Seiten, hat aber anderseits andere Erfordernisse als etwa der Stil von Romanen.
Die aufgeführten Beisiele haben nichts mit Nominalstil zu tun, bei dem statt einfacher Verben unnötige Verbalausdrücke 
mit der Substantivform des Verbs und einem Füllverb verwendet werden. Ich finde eigentlich in den angeführten Beispielen 
nichts, was zu monieren wäre. Stilbetrachtungen an Zeitungen auszuführen, ist so eine Sache.
Man muß bedenken, unter welchem Zeitdruck Zeitungen und Zeitschriften entstehen und wie oft sie aus den verschiedensten 
Gründen geändert werden müssen. Dabei können Formulierungen entstehen, die nicht optimal sind, aber Zeitungen und Zeitschriften
 sind keine Romane.

Comment: Wenn ich nach dieser Formulierungsweise googeln will - welchen Ausdruck muss ich dann verwenden? Es handelt sich also nicht um Nominalstil? Können Sie das belegen?

Comment: @Raffael  Ich sehe kein substantiviertes  Verb und kein Füllverb. Glaube nicht, dass das eine besondere Stilfigur ist. Ich betrachte diese Titel als normale Fügungen, auch wenn sie an bekannte Buchtitel oder Filmtitel angelehnt sind und etwas Einprägsames haben.

Comment: Dieser Stil ist zu prägnant und charakteristisch, als, dass ich glauben kann, dass es hierfür keine (wenigstens informelle) Bezeichnung gibt. Auf SZ, NZZ, FAZ etc. werden sie lange nach solchen Titeln suchen müssen. Ich bin zu Stolz die Bild zu lesen - SPON ist seit 15 Jahren meine Alternative, um meinen Selbstrespekt nicht zu verlieren :D

Comment: @Raffael  Ich sehe wirklich nicht, was es an einem Filmtitel wie "Die bitteren Tränen der Petra von Kant" (FAssbinder) zu bemängeln gibt. In der normalen Fügung "die bitteren Tränen des Mädchens" steht hier für "des Mädchens" ein Personenname.

Comment: Da habe ich persönlich und subjektiv auch absolut nichts auszusetzen, wenn das betitelte Produkt erkennbar keinen Anspruch auf Objektivität erhebt - also bei Film- und Romantiteln zum Beispiel.